# SQL Server + select row and its sub table contents

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have simple select statement like this:

```
SELECT 
[NAME], 
[AGE], 
[GENDER], 
SELECT [PHOTOS] FROM [USERPHOTOS] WHERE... --Yes, this is wrong but just want to make my intentions clearer. 
FROM PEOPLE WHERE AGE = '20'
```

The selected people may have multiple photos in another table, how can I select this sort of query so that I can grab the photos as well?

Comment: Couple questions - Which RDBMS?  Sample data/desired results?  And what are your table structures (how do userphotos and people relate)?

Comment: @sgeddes : too many questions..

Answer (score 3):

Use joins:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

```
SELECT 
[NAME], 
[AGE], 
[GENDER],
[Photo]
From [People]
Inner join [PHOTOS] on People.ID = Photo.OwnerID

WHERE AGE = '20'
```

I assume that photo and people does not have same column names to avoid ambiguous column names.
and i assume that there is a foreign key in the photo table that point sot a person.